# Is immunotherapy effective against allergies?

Tags: allergy, allergen

I have been suffering from allergies for years and I have recently seen an allergist. I was told that I would be a good candidate for immunotherapy. However, it is not an inexpensive process and a pretty hefty time commitment too. Are there studies that show that immunotherapy is effective? Is it more effective for some allergies rather than others? Note that I mostly suffer from environmental allergies and not food allergies.